# Visual Studio Profiler: Memory Allocation View for Cloud Service

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, profiler, azure-worker-roles, azure-cloud-services

I am using Azure SDK 2.4, Visual Studio 2013 to develop and deploy Worker Role to Azure Cloud Service.
To understand Memory Allocations for Worker Role, I am using Visual Studio Profiler.
Configured below mentioned settings on Publish Wizard at the time of deployment:

> Build : Debug
>   Enabled Profiling
>   Selected .NET Memory Allocation (Sampling) as method of profiling

[image: Build : Debug]

[image: Enabled Profiling]

[image: .NET Memory Allocation]

But in the downloaded report, I dont see [Memory Allocation View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms242740.aspx).
Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

You need to click "Show All Code" on the profiling report.

[image]

Once you have done that you would see the Memory Allocation View.

[image]